# Notepad++: How to STOP replacing tabs with spaces?

Tags: notepad++

Since 20 minutes this piece of software is driving me nuts - I UNchecked "replace tabs with spaces" but notepad++ does it anyway! How do I deactivate that?

[image]

Comment: Which language do you use? Maybe for that specific language, the option is still set.

Comment: Works for me, I don't know any other ways to do.

Comment: Works for me too immediately without closing Notepad++ or closing the opened text files. Notepad++ Version 7.7.1 on Windows 10 version 1903.